# How can I compare two strings in NUnitLite?

Tags: .net, nunit

Env: Win 8.1 64, .NET 4.0, VS2013, ReSharper

When using NUnitLite (v1.0.0.0) Assert, it raises a `System.NullReferenceException`

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace DukasFeeder.Core.Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class DukasReaderTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void Assert_GivenStrings_WhenAssert_ReturnsTrue()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual("abc", "abc");
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

I'm running the test via ReSharper. The test fails with:

```
System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  at NUnit.Framework.Assert.That(Object actual, IResolveConstraint expression, String message, Object[] args) in d:\Dev\NUnit\nunitlite\work\src\framework\Assert.cs: line 282
  at NUnit.Framework.Assert.AreEqual(Object expected, Object actual) in d:\Dev\NUnit\nunitlite\work\src\framework\Assert.cs: line 1493
  at DukasFeeder.Core.Tests.DukasReaderTests.Assert_GivenStrings_WhenAssert_ReturnsTrue() in DukasReaderTests.cs: line 18
```

All my other tests work well but with moq.Verify. This was the first test that asserts on NUnit.

If I change the NUnit version from NUnitLite to NUnit.framework it works fine.

Is there something to consider when using NUnitLite? Or do I simply have to use the full NUnit.Framework?

Edit:

What is the point of using NUnitLite (other than that it's newer)? It's bigger than NUnit

[image: NUnitLite vs NUnit]

Comment: NUnitLite's own web site http://nunitlite.org/ says that it was intended for the smaller platforms such as embedded projects or mobile applications. That's the point of it. If your project/environment is fine with NUnit, I'd personally say to use that, but that's hardly an answer to your question.

Comment: Also, [this NUnit support post by Charlie Poole](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/nunitlite/286wZABFZ6w/X5TfU4xgAPMJ) lists the features which are (and which are not) supported in it.

Comment: @ClickRick, I found the following in the mentioned post: 'NUnitLite can run under Microsoft .NET V1.0 through 3.5 on all Windows
platforms beginning with Windows 95.'. I'm using .NET 4.0!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your edit, you're running on .NET 4.0. NUnitLite only supports up to .NET 3.5, so the recommendation is to use NUnit.